# Find the volume of revolution

Tags: calculus, volume

Calculate the volume of the solid generated by rotating the region $\{x=1,y=2,y=x\}$ along the y-axis.

My problem:My region is a triangle,how I can calculate this?I know the formula for curvilinear regions not triangle.Please help me.

Comment: Try to think what figure would you get after rotating right triangle along on of its catheti.

Comment: If you think about the region visually, you should realize that it's a hollowed out cone-frustum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use shell method :

$$ V=\int_a^b 2\pi x f(x)\ dx $$

This revolution-solid can be cut into shells : $$ Height=f(x),\  radius=x,\ Volume\ of\ a\ shell = 2\pi x f(x)\ \Delta x
$$

Here $$ a=1 \leq x\leq b=2,\ f(x)= 2-x $$ so that $$ V=\int_1^2
  2\pi x (2-x)\ dx =\frac{4\pi}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: What would be the volume of the region bounded by $x=0,x=1,y=1,y=2$ rotated about the $y$-axis? What about the volume of the region bounded by $x=0,y=x,y=1,y=2$? How can you use this to find your answer?